# Error- 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers,

Tags: python, matplotlib, classification, scatter-plot, prediction

This is the code I am getting an error with. Can anyone help me with this?

```py
plt.scatter(
    x = y_test.index, 
    y = [1] * len(y_test),
    c = (accuracy_data != True).astype(float),
    marker = '.',
    cmap = cmap,
)
```

> Error- 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers

`accuracy_data` is a DataFrame of true/false values. (But I guess I have done something wrong in the code as the entire column is filled with False.)

I am trying to run a classification ML algorithm on the Nifty data set (Index for Indian Stock Market) for 25 years and trying to predict next day closing prices. The train and test data is in the ratio of 4:1.

Comment: Try `c='blue'` or `c=['blue', 'red']` or `c=[0,1,2]` or something similar. It looks like you are passing data in the wrong format. Please check the return value of `(accuracy_data != True).astype(float)`. Maybe [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html#sphx-glr-gallery-shapes-and-collections-scatter-py) example helps you.

Comment: What is `accuracy_data`?  For the code to work, it needs to be a numpy array of True/False values with the same length as `y_test`.  Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70907984/edit) your post and add some reproducible test data? Can you print out `print(accuracy_data)`?

Comment: accuracy_data is a DataFrame of true/false values. But I guess i have done somethng wrong in the code as the entire column is filled with False Values

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html#):

> **`c`:** array-like or list of colors or color, optional
>
> The marker colors. Possible values:
>
> - **A scalar or sequence of *n* numbers to be mapped to colors using `cmap` and `norm`.**
> - A 2D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA.
> - A sequence of colors of length *n*.
> - A single color format string.
>
> Note that `c` should not be a single numeric RGB or RGBA sequence because that is indistinguishable from an array of values to be colormapped. If you want to specify the same RGB or RGBA value for all points, use a 2D array with a single row. Otherwise, value- matching will have precedence in case of a size matching with *x* and *y*.
>
> If you wish to specify a single color for all points prefer the color keyword argument.

Now, this is a guess. I've not used MatPlotLib or Pandas. But it looks like you're turning the entire `accuracy_data` into a single value and turning it into a `float`?

Could you try turning the dataframe into a list of `0.0` and `1.0` floats?
(`float(False) == 0.0; float(True) == 1.0`)

```py
plt.scatter(
    x = y_test.index, 
    y = [1] * len(y_test),
    c = [float(x) for x in accuracy_data]
    marker = '.',
    cmap = cmap,
)
```